# TextView setText options

Tags: android

Trying to set a TextView, to a certain message containing a variable.

for Example

```
tvOddEven.setText("You have entered:", odd, "% of numbers");
```

odd is an int variable

it's giving me an error, that I can't use those parameters.

ideas?

Answer (score 5):

`tvOddEven.setText("You have entered:" + odd + "% of numbers");`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
tvOddEven.setText("You have entered:" + String.valueOf(odd) + "% of numbers");
```

Since odd is not a String you need to convert it to string.